# Packaging with autotools for Ubuntu

Tags: makefile

I've developed a C application for Ubuntu and created the [installer](https://launchpad.net/~unixinfo/+archive/ubuntu/openshell/+packages). The file structure is

```
├── autom4te.cache
├── build-aux
├── contrib
├── debian
│   └── source
├── doc
├── gnulib
│   ├── lib
│   └── m4
├── man
├── po
├── src
└── tests
```

**configure.ac**

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
dnl
dnl This file is free software; as a special exception the author gives
dnl unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it, with or without
dnl modifications, as long as this notice is preserved.
dnl
dnl This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
dnl WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law; without even the
dnl implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

AC_INIT([GNU Hello], [2.7], [bug-hello@gnu.org])

dnl Must come before AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE.
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([readme-alpha dist-xz])

# Minimum Autoconf version required.
AC_PREREQ(2.60)

# Where to generate output; srcdir location.
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h:config.in])dnl Keep filename to 8.3 for MS-DOS.
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main.c])

dnl Checks for programs.
# We need a C compiler.
AC_PROG_CC

# Since we use gnulib: gl_EARLY must be called as soon as possible after
# the C compiler is checked.  The others could be later, but we just
# keep everything together.
gl_EARLY
gl_INIT

# GNU help2man creates man pages from --help output; in many cases, this
# is sufficient, and obviates the need to maintain man pages separately.
# However, this means invoking executables, which we generally cannot do
# when cross-compiling, so we test to avoid that (the variable
# "cross_compiling" is set by AC_PROG_CC).
if test $cross_compiling = no; then
  AM_MISSING_PROG(HELP2MAN, help2man)
else
  HELP2MAN=:
fi

# i18n support from GNU gettext.
AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION([0.18.1])
AM_GNU_GETTEXT([external])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
           contrib/Makefile
           doc/Makefile
           gnulib/lib/Makefile
           man/Makefile
           po/Makefile.in
           src/Makefile
           tests/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Top-level **Makefile.am**

```
# Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in (in this,
# and all subdirectories).
# Makefile for the top-level directory of GNU hello.
# 
# Copyright 1997, 1998, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011
# Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
# any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# Find gnulib headers.
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I gnulib/m4

# Additional files to distribute.
EXTRA_DIST = ChangeLog.O gnulib/m4/gnulib-cache.m4

# Subdirectories to descend into.
SUBDIRS = contrib gnulib/lib po src doc man

# `make diff' produces a diff against the previous version, given both
# .tar.gz's in the current directory.  This should only be done when an
# official release is made (and only if you care to provide diffs).
#
hello_pre = 2.6
diff: diffcheck
    @(echo "To apply these patches, cd to the main directory of the package"; \
      echo "and then use \`patch -p1 <hello-XXX.diff'."; \
      echo "Before building the program, run \`autogen.sh'."; ) > \
        $(PACKAGE)-$(hello_pre)-$(VERSION).diff
    -diff -rc2P --exclude=configure --exclude=config.h.in --exclude=*.info \
        --exclude=*.gmo --exclude=aclocal.m4 \
        $(PACKAGE)-$(hello_pre) $(PACKAGE)-$(VERSION) >> \
        $(PACKAGE)-$(hello_pre)-$(VERSION).diff
    gzip --force --best $(PACKAGE)-$(hello_pre)-$(VERSION).diff

diffcheck:
    for d in $(PACKAGE)-$(hello_pre) $(PACKAGE)-$(VERSION) ; do \
        if test ! -d $$d ; then \
         if test -r $$d.tar.gz ; then \
                tar -zxf $$d.tar.gz ; \
                else \
             echo subdir $$d does not exist. ; \
                exit 1 ; \
                fi ; \
        fi ; \
    done


# Verify that all source files using _() are listed in po/POTFILES.in.
# The idea is to run this before making pretests, as well as official
# releases, so that translators will be sure to have all the messages.
# (From coreutils.)
po-check:
    if test -f po/POTFILES.in; then                 \
      grep -E -v '^(#|$$)' po/POTFILES.in    \
     | grep -v '^src/false\.c$$' | sort > $@-1;            \
      files=;                           \
      for file in $$($(CVS_LIST_EXCEPT)) `find * -name '*.[ch]'`; do \
     case $$file in                     \
        djgpp/* | man/*) continue;;                 \
        esac;                           \
        case $$file in      \
     *.[ch])       \
       base=`expr " $$file" : ' \(.*\)\..'`;           \
          { test -f $$base.l || test -f $$base.y; } && continue;;   \
        esac;                           \
        files="$$files $$file";                 \
      done;                             \
      grep -E -l '\b(N?_|gettext *)\([^)"]*("|$$)' $$files       \
        | sort -u > $@-2;                       \
      diff -u $@-1 $@-2 || exit 1;                  \
      rm -f $@-1 $@-2;                      \
    fi


# Example of updating the online web pages for the documentation
# with the gendocs.sh script; see
# http://www.gnu.org/prep/maintain/html_node/Invoking-gendocs_002esh.html
#
gnulib = $(HOME)/gnu/src/gnulib
gendocs = $(gnulib)/build-aux/gendocs.sh
gendocs_templates = $(gnulib)/doc
gendocs_envvars = GENDOCS_TEMPLATE_DIR=$(gendocs_templates)
#
manual = hello
manual_title = "Hello, GNU World"
email = bug-hello@gnu.org
gendocs_args = --email $(email) $(manual) $(manual_title)
#
www_target = $(HOME)/gnu/www/hello/manual
#
doctemp = doc/wwwtemp
wwwdoc:
    rm -rf $(doctemp) && mkdir $(doctemp)
    cd $(doctemp) \
    && ln -s ../*.texi . \
    && env $(gendocs_envvars) $(gendocs) $(gendocs_args)
    cp -arf $(doctemp)/manual/. $(www_target)
    ls -ltu $(www_target)/html_node | tail  # cvs rm -f obsolete files
# followed by cvs add of new files and cvs commit.
```

src level **Makefile.am**

```
# Makefile.am for hello/src.
#
# Copyright 1996, 1997, 2001, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 Free Software
# Foundation, Inc.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
# any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

bin_PROGRAMS = opsh
opsh_SOURCES = edit.c eval.c exec.c expr.c funcs.c histrap.c jobs.c lalloc.c lex.c main.c misc.c shf.c syn.c tree.c var.c

opsh_LDADD = @LIBINTL@ ../gnulib/lib/libgnu.a -lbsd -L/lib


localedir = $(datadir)/locale

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/gnulib/lib -I$(top_builddir)/gnulib/lib
DEFS = -DLOCALEDIR=\"$(localedir)\" @DEFS@
```

Comment: Is *your* program actually copyright FSF (and called `hello/src`)?  If not, then those comments need an update!

Comment: @TobySpeight The program in the question was my first non-trivial autotools project so I changed only what I needed and will update those comments now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good. Ship it.

Your first two files appear to be all or mostly boilerplate, with maybe the set of subdirs being project specific.

It seems likely the link editor would already look in /lib, so `-L/lib` may be redundant. And `-lbsd` seems like a blast from the past.

I imagine that `dh_make` / `debuild` work cleanly with your package.